# Is a system with the same number of equations and unknowns underdetermined if two equations are the same?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to get a grasp of the idea of underdetermined/overdetermined systems. Let's stick to underdetermined systems for now.

I understand that an underdetermined system has fewer equations than unknowns, like this:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x+y+z=1 \\ 
x+y+2z=3
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

**But what about a system like this**, where two equations are basically the same?
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x+y+z=1 \\ 
x+y+2z=3 \\
2x+2y+4z=6 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

There are now just as many equations as unknowns, yet I would still think that such a system is *underdetermined*, since only the first two equations actually give us any information, but [Wikipedia says that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdetermined_system)

> A system of linear equations [...] is considered underdetermined if
>   there are fewer equations than unknowns [...].

which, as far as I understand, means that this second system is not underdetermined.

Comment: The definition you provide for "underdetermined" is informal, not precise.  The system $x+y+z=1,x+y+z=2$ is hardly "underdetermined".   As you correctly point out, you need to ask if the system of equations is independent and consistent.

Comment: You're right. Maybe they could say "if there are fewer linearly independent equations than unknowns"

Comment: The Wikipedia definition is clearly wrong. You are right. You can't tell if a system is undetermined simply by counting equations and variables.

Comment: The row echelon form (of the augmented matrix) makes it clear (a) if the system is consistent, and (b) if there are enough linearly independent rows to determine all the unknowns.

Comment: in this case you can actually prove no solutions in the positive reals work.  if x+y+z=1 then x+y<1 but by equation 2 that would mean that 2z >2 meaning z>1.  a contradiction on the positive reals.

Comment: I think what the book or the source that you are using means by saying if there are fewer equations than the unknowns  is that if there are fewer _linearly independent_ equations than the unknowns